# Azure CLI Command to display Instance Name and Resource group

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-virtual-machine, azure-cli, azure-cloud-services

I am writing a script and I would have the private IP address, is their way to fetch Instance Name and resource group from az cli

```
az vm list-ip-addresses --output table
VirtualMachine        PublicIPAddresses    PrivateIPAddresses
--------------------  -------------------  --------------------
Test1                                      10.0.0.4
Test2                                      10.0.0.3
Test3                                      10.0.0.2
Test4                                      10.0.0.1
```

I tried using query, something like this but no luck `az vm list-ip-addresses --output json --query 'virtualMachine.name[]'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fetch Instance Name and resource group from az CLI, you can use

```
az vm list-ip-addresses --query "[].virtualMachine" -o table
```

[image]

Or with the command, you can get the VM name, private IP address, resource group.

```
az vm list-ip-addresses --query "[].virtualMachine.[name,network.privateIpAddresses,resourceGroup]" -o table
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a ton, Nacy! It helped me achieved what I need to do